# How to get first level of children by LINQ

Tags: asp.net, xml, linq

I have such XMl

```
<root>
    <list>
        <list>
            <topic></topic>
            <topic></topic>
        </list>
        <topic></topic>
        <topic></topic>
    </list>
    <topic></topic>
    <topic></topic>
    <topic></topic>
</root>
```

I need to get the first level of children:

```
<list></list>
<topic></topic>
<topic></topic>
<topic></topic>
```

I try to do like this

```
var list = x.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name == "list" || e.Name == "topic");
```

But it returns all topics and lists.

Please help! :)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Just `document.Root.Elements()` should work.

Basically [`Descendants()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.descendants.aspx) recurses, whereas [`Elements()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.elements.aspx) only gets *direct* children.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - Did you mean 'Document.Root.Elements()' instead of 'document.RootElement.Elements()'?

Comment: @Jon Skeet Either way, your answer helped me... thank you! +1 :)